# bash_profile alias: command not found - not a unicode issue

Tags: bash, macos, macos-sierra

So I've just begun installing packages and software on my new work MBP.
I have a set of alias commands that I'm migrating from the last work machine and having hiccups right out the gate.

I have a .bash_profile file in my home directory:
[bash profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ27l.png)

In my bash file for testing is a single alias, which contains normal "" quotes:
[alias example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuduF.png)

When running the alias in terminal, the following error is produced:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dSkt.png)

I tested to see if the aliased command actually works with bash and it does:
[aliased command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI09b.png)

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Don't expect readers to goto remote sites to view your problem description. You should cut/paste exact code and error messages into your Q and use the `{}` tool from the menu at the top left of the edit box to format your code/data/errors so they are easily searchable and readable.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Did you verify that the alias is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Quoting from the close-as-MCVE reason, with emphasis added: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Putting something behind a link means it's not in the question itself, by definition.

Comment: Also, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) describing why we don't accept screenshots of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what your terminal is telling you is that the command `‘ls` -- with the quote character in the beginning -- doesn't exist.

I get the same behavior from doing

```
bash-3.2$ alias ll="‘ls -lG"
bash-3.2$ ll
bash: ‘ls: command not found
```

So I'm guessing you accidentally pasted or put an extra quote character (`‘`) in there.

Comment: Not sure how the heck that got in there, let alone not noticing it!